# Ich kann den Kasus eines Wortes nicht einsehen: "Der Grund … war rein praktischer Natur"

Tags: grammatical-case

ich habe gerade auf einen Satz gestoßen: „Aber der Grund für den Knick in der Kurve war rein *praktischer Natur*.“

(Frage 1:) Ich frage mich, ob die "Natur" hier Genitiv ist oder Dativ. Und solche grammatische Struktur ist für mich nicht ganz verständlich. Hier ist die "Natur" auf keinen Fall Nominativ. D.h., dieser Satz ist anders als Sätze wie: "Ich bin ein Mann" oder "Das ist ein Auto". (Frage 2:) Wie soll ich diesen Satz verstehen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [der Meinung / der Ansicht sein: What is the case in these examples?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54997/der-meinung-der-ansicht-sein-what-is-the-case-in-these-examples)

Comment: Hello David, thank you for the link. I did already know about that expression ("ich bin der Meinung, dass …"). But I was not sure whether this expression ("etwas ist einer Natur") has the same grammatical structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"einer Natur sein" ist eine feststehende Wendung mit 'Natur' im Genitiv.

Damit beschreibt man eine Eigenschaft vom Subjekt des Satzes. Im konkreten Beispiel hier also "Aber der Grund für den Knick in der Kurve war rein praktischer Natur": das könnte man umschreiben zu "Der Knick in der Kurve hatte rein praktische Gründe".

Nicht zu verwechseln ist dieses mit der ähnlichen Formulierung "in der Natur einer Sache liegen" in der Natur im Dativ steht.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Sie hat mir geholfen!