# Adjektiv Deklination in Form von Genitiv

Tags: adjective, genitive, adjective-ending

Warum sind die Adjektive "ausländisch" und "bäuerlich" in den folgenden Sätze in der Form eines Genitivs? Ich vermute, dass "waren" und "sind" eigentlich den Nominativ brauchen.

> Im letzten Jahr beriet der Verein 448 Frauen, 35 ‌Prozent von ihnen waren **ausländischer Herkunft.**
> Meine Vorfahren sind **bäuerlicher Herkunft.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Genitiv

Sätze mit `sein` und Genitiv werden verwendet, um eine Eigenschaft des Subjekts zu beschreiben. Das Objekt im Genitiv ist dabei die beschriebene Eigenschaft (in diesem Fall die Herkunft).

Man könnte auch sagen:

> Die Herkunft meiner Vorfahren ist bäuerlich.

**Weitere Beispiele mit anderen Wörtern:**

> Die Störungen waren natürlichen Ursprungs.
>
> [Der Grund war praktischer Natur.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/ich-kann-den-kasus-eines-wortes-nicht-einsehen-der-grund-war-rein-praktische)
>
> Ich bin königlichen Bluts.
>
> Die Musik ist klassischer Art.
>
> Er ist schlechter Verfassung.
>
> Sie ist anderer Meinung.

Die Bedeutung ist hier ebenfalls "Das Genitivobjekt des Subjekts ist adjektiv".

In alten Texten taucht manchmal auch "von" + Dativ auf (*"Du bist von großer Macht."*)

#### Nominativ

Sätze mit `sein` und Nominativ werden verwendet, um das Subjekt selbst zu beschreiben:

> Meine Vorfahren sind Bauern.

"Meine Vorfahren sind bäuerliche Herkunft" ergibt hier keinen Sinn, weil Herkunft ein abstraktes Konzept ist.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: English has a similar construction with "sth is of XX type / provenance / heritage /...", e.g. "My ancestors are of a farmer provenance"

Comment: @xyldke Herzlichen Dank für ihre Antwort.

Comment: Den letzten Satz verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: Herkunft ist kein Ding, sondern ein Konzept. Die Vorfahren sind jedoch Dinge. Der Satz drückt aus, dass die Vorfahren buchstäblich die Herkunft sind, aber ein Ding kann nicht gleichzeitig ein Konzept sein. Eine Ausnahme sind Metaphern, die mit genau dieser Unmöglichkeit spielen.

Comment: "Diese Konstruktion wird nur mit wenigen Wörtern verwendet." Da bin ich *anderer Meinung*, ziehe *frohen Mutes* von dannen und erfreue mich *der Reaktionen*. Genitivobjekte können mit so ziemlich allen Verben gebildet werden.

Comment: @bakunin Da hast du Recht. Ich wollte ursprünglich auf das Konstrukt "sein" + Genitiv hinaus, aber auch die kann grundsätzlich mit allen Wörtern verwendet werden (wobei "Das Auto ist kleinen Motors" wohl weniger Verwendung findet). Ich habe die Antwort angepasst.

Comment: Wenn das "Auto kleinen Motors ist", dann ist es wahrscheinlich "schwächlicher Statur", was dazu führen könnte, daß es des Nächtens auf der Autobahn des Todes ist, wenn es sich von der rechten Spur weg wagt. ;-) Danke fürs Ändern.

Comment: @bakunin Genitiv*objekte* im eigentlichen Sinn gibt es nur mit wenigen Verben, aber häufig kann ein sog. absoluter Genitiv als Adverbial verwendet weden. "Frohen Mutes" ist ein Beispiel dafür.

Comment: @RHa: Danke, wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @planetmaker: Frage und Antwort wurden in deutscher Sprache verfasst. Du weißt nicht, welche anderen Sprachen der Fragesteller beherrscht, und ob Englisch eine dieser Sprachen ist. Wenn du sicher gehen willst, dass dich der Fragensteller verstehen, dass schreibe deine Kommentare bitte in derselben Sprache wie die Frage, im vorliegenden Fall also bitte auf Deutsch.